# Perform Something when Cookie is set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a third-party tracking script enabled on my site. This java-script basically adds a cookie on the first visit and in the subsequent visits it tracks the site.

I have en edge-case scenario(the first page load during which the tracking script adds the cookie for the first time) where on the very first page load I need to perform some operation once the cookie is set. But since I am using a third party tracking code, I cannot change that code and need to know when that script sets the cookie on the page. If I know when the cookie is set then I will write some javascript code to perform some operation based on this cookie value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mymodule.cookieReady = function () {
    myCookie = Mymodule.getCookie('xyz');

        if (cookieReadySet) {
            clearTimeout(cookieReadySet);
        }
        cookieReadySet = setTimeout(Mymodule.cookieReady, 10);
        return cookieReadySet;
};

Mymodule.getCookie = function(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```